# Interfacing with an IP stack between embedded flash partitions

Tags: c, embedded, powerpc, flash-memory

I have a TCP/IP stack that I need to share between my boot partition and my application partition. The stack is initialized in the boot code and both boot and the application make use of the stack. Both partitions reside in the same flash memory module, but in different flash sections so they do not erase each other. To share the stack, I created a constant function structure that is placed at a specified memory location in flash. The compiler I'm working with is Freescale's Embedded PowerPC tools. In my boot code it looks like this:

ethernet.h

```
typedef Ethernet_Struct = {
     int (*enet_init) (void);
     void (*enet_release) (void);
     int  (*enet_bind)(...);
     int  (*enet_recvfrom)(...);
}

extern const Ethernet_Struct enet;
```

ethernet.c

```
const Ethernet_Struct enet = {
     enet_init,
     enet_release,
     enet_bind,
     enet_recvfrom
}
```

Then the linker places this object file at 0x1ffc0 (flash) and everything looks well in my map file. The linker symbol that refers to this location is _ENET_STRUCT_. In my application, I do this:

app.c

```
#include "ethernet.h"
extern uint32 _ENET_STRUCT_;
const Ethernet_Struct *enet = (Ethernet_Struct *) &_ENET_STRUCT_;

void main() {
    enet->enet_init();   /* In the assembly, it's trying to 
                           branch to a location that is not even in flash */
}
```

I would think that enet would be placed in .rodata like it was in the boot code, but it actually goes to .sdata. No worries, when I go to copy the sdata section from ROM to RAM, enet is pointing to 0x1ffc0. The debugger even shows the correct location. But then the assembly shows that it's trying to branch to somewhere not even in flash or RAM. My best guess about what is happening here is the compiler has no idea where enet is pointing since it is relying on the linker to get that address.

This actually works, though I don't like having a explicit value for an address:

```
#define enet ((Ethernet_Struct *) 0x1ffc0)
```

So, what is the correct way to create an interface between partitions?

Comment: When you copy ROM to RAM, this must be taken into account in your linker control file. Maybe it would help if you showed it?